# Testing a whole script in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing

What is the best way of testing a whole script? I want to test if a script returns (prints) a correct result. So far what I have is another script that more or less does just:

`# test.rb`

```
expected = 'test'
output = `script.rb --many params`
if output != expected
  puts "Error"
end
```

In this example, the script I want to test is called script.rb.
Cheers.

Comment: Normally you write tests on *parts* of your program, and if necessary an "integration test" on the whole thing in more of a black-box manner. Tools like [Travis](http://travis-ci.org) can help automate your testing and verify changes made to code.

Comment: In this case I have some tests on specific methods in my script. But what I'm really interested in is testing the whole script. It's a replacement of some old script and there are a few config files in JSON, many ways of providing user input etc. So I want to test if it behaves exactly like the old script (returns the same result) - this is the most important thing. Methods are not enough because I might have overlooked something that worked with the old script but no longer works with the new.

Comment: You can write a test that does exactly what you have here using basic stuff like `assert`. There's the classic [`test-unit`](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit) library or alternatives like [RSpec](http://rspec.info) if you feel that's not enough.

Answer (score 3):

Using `test-unit` you end up with code like this:

```
class TestScript < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_output
    assert_equal 'test', `script --options`
  end
end
```

You'll probably want to use the [`open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) library when dealing with output from programs as that gives you more control over how that's handled. You could write your own wrapper for that as well, like `assert_output_equal`:

```
def assert_output_equal(output, command, message = nil, &block)
  Open3.popen3(command) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    assert_equal output, stdout.read, message, &block
  end
end
```

You can add on to that to test for the status from your process, ensuring it succeeded, and that there wasn't any output on STDERR and such.

When it comes to testing things that produce a lot of textual output (e.g. JSON data, formatted lists) I find it's best to create files in a place like `test/expect` and compare the file to the output rather than defining the text in the source. This makes it easy to create the files in the first place:

```
old_script > test/expected/old_script.default
old_script --option > test/expected/old_script.with-option
```

It also makes your version control diffs easier to read when something needs to be adjusted in there.

Answer (score 1):

### Define Test Fixtures

> What is the best way of testing a whole script? I want to test if a script returns (prints) a correct result.

You need a *test fixture* that includes a known input value and an expected result. In other words:

1. Given a known input value,
2. When you run the program
3. Then you will receive your *expected* answer as output.

Note that testing an entire program this way can tell you if you got the right results from a set of inputs, but it will generally *not* provide insight into where the problem is. However, many forms of acceptance testing using this "black box" approach to testing, so it's certainly a reasonable approach as long as you understand the limitations.

### Possible Frameworks

The list of possible testing frameworks is not infinite, but if you don't want to write your own test harness from scratch you may want to try one of the more popular ones. Some possibilities to kick-start your own research include:

- [Bats](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats)
- [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/)
- [Aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba)

There are of course plenty of others, but per your original question you will probably want to focus on ATDD or BDD testing tools, rather than unit testing, if you want to test the entire script rather than its component parts.

Comment: We develop another CLI testing framework, [Should](http://www.should-test.net). It can also count occurrences, look for regular expressions, use variables, or check exit codes.